# Pymongo Or Condition To Filter Queries

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

so I am having a little bit of trouble going through mongoDB with pymongo and using the or condition. Looked at all similar posts, but for some reason, mine doesn't seem to work.

```
        goodShots = coll.find({"Tag" : "zombiegame", "Meta.levelState":"NORMAL_MODE", "$or":[
            {"Meta.zombiesInLOS":{'$gt':0}}, {"Meta.zombiesInSLOS":{'$gt':0}},
             {"Meta.helpersInLOS":{'$gt':0}}, {"Meta.helpersInSLOS":{'gt':0}}
            ]})

        goodShot01 = coll.find({"Tag" : "zombiegame", "Meta.levelState" : "NORMAL_MODE", "Meta.zombiesInLOS" : {"$gt" : 0}})
        goodShot02 = coll.find({"Tag" : "zombiegame", "Meta.levelState" : "NORMAL_MODE", "Meta.zombiesInSLOS" : {"$gt" : 0}})
        goodShot03 = coll.find({"Tag" : "zombiegame", "Meta.levelState" : "NORMAL_MODE", "Meta.helpersInLOS" : {"$gt" : 0}})
        goodShot04 = coll.find({"Tag" : "zombiegame", "Meta.levelState" : "NORMAL_MODE", "Meta.helpersInSLOS" : {"$gt" : 0}})
```

The first query 'goodShots' should technically return queries that have all the other conditions in 'goodShot01-04.' However, it returns 0. 'goodShot01-04' returns a count > 0 though.

Answer (score 0):

If I insert 4 documents like

```
{ 
    "Tag" : "zombiegame",
    "Meta" : {
        "levelState" : "NORMAL_MODE",
        "zombiesInLOS" : 1
    }
}
```

varying the last field in `Meta` through the 4 possibilities, then I find all four documents with the `goodShots` query and each appropriate document for `goodShot01` through `goodShot04`. I had to add in a missing $ in the last clause of the `$or` to find 4 instead of 3 documents. Perhaps check again that you are putting in the right query?